# How to move from one set of buttons to another with pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to implement moving from one set of buttons to another in telegram bot for each user separately, like at the screenshots below, I clicked button with text "Ответы на вопросы" and I was moved to another set of buttons

[image]

[image]

Here is problem, that for each user state about buttons have to store separately. Now I have only one idea how to implement this: to store user-id and state in key-value db.

Are there another solutions to solve this problem more simple, maybe with just resources of `pytelegrambotapi`? And changes of state can be implemented with just automatons or there are another ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `finite state machine` implemented in `pytelegrambotapi`.

To work properly with user's state, you should use the [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) framework instead of telebot.

You can find a basic example of using FSM [here](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py).